# How to make hotword detection service in android

Tags: java, android, service, voice-recognition, google-speech-api

I want to create a service that should listens for hotword in background such that when i say hello it should invoke an activity, how can i do this, about voiceInteractionService but I have read that Its not available to use, is it true? could anyone tell me the way i should solve this problem? Its about hotword detector

I have been following [this](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/tests/VoiceInteraction/src/com/android/test/voiceinteraction/)

Tried this:

```
public class InteractionService extends VoiceInteractionService {

static final String TAG = "InteractionService" ;
private AlwaysOnHotwordDetector mHotwordDetector;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.i(TAG, "service started");
}

@Override
public void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating " + this);

    mHotwordDetector = createAlwaysOnHotwordDetector("Hello"
,  Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), mHotwordCallback);
    Log.i(TAG, "onReady");
}

private final AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.Callback mHotwordCallback = 
new AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.Callback() {
           @Override
           public void onAvailabilityChanged(int status) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onAvailabilityChanged(" + status + ")");
                    hotwordAvailabilityChangeHelper(status);
                }

                    @Override
            public void onDetected(AlwaysOnHotwordDetector
               .EventPayload eventPayload) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onDetected");
                }

                    @Override
            public void onError() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onError");
                }

                    @Override
            public void onRecognitionPaused() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onRecognitionPaused");
                }

                    @Override
            public void onRecognitionResumed() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onRecognitionResumed");
                }
        };

private void hotwordAvailabilityChangeHelper(int status) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Hotword availability = " + status);
    switch (status) {
        case AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.STATE_HARDWARE_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_HARDWARE_UNAVAILABLE");
            break;
        case AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.STATE_KEYPHRASE_UNSUPPORTED:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_KEYPHRASE_UNSUPPORTED");
            break;
        case AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.STATE_KEYPHRASE_UNENROLLED:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_KEYPHRASE_UNENROLLED");
            Intent enroll = mHotwordDetector.createEnrollIntent();
            Log.i(TAG, "Need to enroll with " + enroll);
            break;
        case AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.STATE_KEYPHRASE_ENROLLED:
            Log.i(TAG, "STATE_KEYPHRASE_ENROLLED - starting recognition");
            if (mHotwordDetector.startRecognition(0)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "startRecognition succeeded");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "startRecognition failed");
            }
            break;
    }

    //    final static AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.Callback
}}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you get answer for this?

Comment: Not yet you can post new question, i will help you there

Comment: Hi! I posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371813/hotworddetector-using-voiceinteractionservice-in-android. Please do the needful

Comment: Okau i will see

Answer (score -2):

Porcupine's [service demo](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/tree/master/demo/android/Service) does exactly this.

Comment: No it does not, the op requested help for the official way to set up voice assistant, maybe to replace google own assistant, or bixby on samsung. Porcupine does not replace such things.